# Difference between onSingleTapConfirmed and onSingleTapUp

Tags: android, onclick, touch, gesture

What is the difference between `onSingleTapConfirmed` and `onSingleTapUp` in `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener`? Which one of these is similar to `onClick` methods?

Comment: implement both, do some Log.d logging in both, perform simple tap gesture, see the logcat, perform double tap gesture, see the logcat, also none of them are similar to onClick

Comment: @pskink is it possible to derive a method that behaves like onclick from these methods?

Comment: no, i dont think so, you have to use setOnClickListener

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to the [`GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html) documentation,

> #### `onSingleTapConfirmed`
>
> Notified when a single-tap occurs.
>
> Unlike `onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent)`, this will only be called after the
>   detector is confident that the user's first tap is not followed by a
>   second tap leading to a double-tap gesture.
>
> #### `onSingleTapUp`
>
> Notified when a tap occurs with the up MotionEvent that triggered it.

I think the `onClick` method is similar to `onSingleTapConfirmed`.

Comment: If you need fast reactions and you do not support double taps, than `onSingleTapUp` will give you the event faster.

Comment: IMO `onSingleTapUp` is the way to go if you want something similar to `onClick`. Because `onSingleTapConfirmed` will give you a delay which puzzles the user.

Answer (score 0):

The `onSingleTapUp()` callback will occur when a tap gesture takes place with an up motion that triggered it, whilst `onSingleTapConfirmed()` will occur when a detected tap gesture is confirmed by the system as a single tap and not part of a double tap gesture.